# python phpserialize loads unicode string failed

Tags: python, character-encoding

here is my serialized string including Chinese characters:

```
'a:2:{s:3:"key";s:0:"";s:8:"solution";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"text";s:6:"**你好";s:3:"fig";N;s:5:"score";i:0;}}}}'
```

here is my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
#coding=utf-8
string='a:2:{s:3:"key";s:0:"";s:8:"solution";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"text";s:6:"**你好";s:3:"fig";N;s:5:"score";i:0;}}}}'
import phpserialize
dict=phpserialize.loads(string)
```

it get errors as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print phpserialize.loads(phpstring,decode_strings=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phpserialize.py", line 522, in loads
    object_hook, array_hook)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phpserialize.py", line 512, in load
    return _unserialize()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phpserialize.py", line 497, in _unserialize
    return array_hook(_load_array())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phpserialize.py", line 463, in _load_array
    item = _unserialize()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phpserialize.py", line 490, in _unserialize
    _expect(b'"')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phpserialize.py", line 444, in _expect
    raise ValueError('failed expectation, expected %r got %r' % (e, v))
ValueError: failed expectation, expected '"' got 'o'
```

I've already found the reason.

In php the Chinese characters are encoded and serialized in UTF-8 as following which containing 6 characters in text:

```
'a:2:{s:3:"key";s:0:"";s:8:"solution";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"text";s:6:"**\u4f60\u597d";s:3:"fig";N;s:5:"score";i:0;}}}}'
```

But when it comes into python the string becomes which containing 8 characters in text:

```
'a:2:{s:3:"key";s:0:"";s:8:"solution";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"text";s:6:"**\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd";s:3:"fig";N;s:5:"score";i:0;}}}}'
```

So when i changed the length from 6 to 8 in the string , it can be load correctly in python.

But there are millions of serialized strings in my database waiting for processing in python.

how to load these Unicode string correctly in Python?

Comment: I am just wondering, how can it be 6 characters in php.

Comment: ah, i see. It might be chinese encoding, which is neither utf8 nor utf16.

Comment: it is utf-8, Chinese character'length is 2 and English letter's is 1~

Comment: No, each chinese characters took 3 characters in utf8, "**\u4f60\u597d" will be 8 characters, not 6 characters, most likely your encoding is big5, '**\xa7A\xa6n', which can be 6 characters.

Comment: read about utf8 in wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look this:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
string = '**你好'
print len(string),
string = string.decode('utf-8')
print len(string),
string = string.encode('gb2312')
print len(string)
# 8 4 6
```

This is why you get errors when you decode the string to utf-8 or unicode. The solution is decoding it to  gb2312, big5, gbk or gb18030. I suggest gb18030 because it is compatible with others.

in addition, specify the charset when you loads your string.like this:

```
dict = phpserialize.loads(string, charset='gb18030')
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: this i know, but still can not correctly load in phpserialize.